# How do I log entering/exiting a function?

Tags: android, logging

I want to do some logging like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   mLog = Logger.getLogger(getLocalClassName());
   mLog.setLevel(Level.ALL);

   mLog.entering("onCreate", "onCreate");
   mLog.exiting("onCreate", "onCreate");
}
```

but logcat window in eclipse show nothing.

Why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Phonon: Please work on providing good answers to StNickolay's previous questions.

Comment: @Tomalak Most of his questions were answered; fully and thoroughly. Ever cared to look?

Answer (score 2):

Use [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

Then try

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("onCreate", "entering");

        Log.i("onCreate", "exiting");
}
```